# Feed an array with spaces to curl

Tags: curl, zsh

Why curl invoked with

```
curl_options=("--verbose" "--user-agent 'Mozilla compatible'"); \
curl $(echo "${curl_options[@]}") icanhazip.com
```

returns an error: "*curl: (6) Could not resolve host: compatible*", that is, it does not understand the quoted string 'Mozilla compatible' as a two-word whole?

The very same command `curl_options=("--verbose" "--user-agent 'Mozilla compatible'"); echo "${curl_options[@]}"` shows that the string is quoted properly: `--verbose --user-agent 'Mozilla compatible'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run

```
mozilla --verbose --user-agent 'Mozilla compatible'
```

`mozilla` sees three arguments:

1. `--verbose`
2. `--user-agent`
3. `Mozilla compatible`

The array should contain the same three words.

```
curl_options=(
   --verbose
   --user-agent
   'Mozilla compatible'
)
```

Then

```
curl "${curl_options[@]}" icanhazip.com  # no echo or command substitution
```

---

The quotes around `Mozilla compatible` are not part *of* the argument; they are used by the shell to prevent `Mozilla` and `compatible` from being treated as two separate arguments.

You *could* write

```
curl_options=(
    --verbose
    --user-agent='Mozilla compatible'
)
```

This defines two different arguments, but `curl` itself will treat the single argument `--user-agent=Mozilla compatible` the same way it treats the adjacent pair of arguments `--user-agent` and `Mozilla compatible`.